# usar dos modelos en una vista mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tengo dos tablas una llamada rol_usario y otra usuario relacionadas entre si, lo que quiero es desplegar en la vista de detalles del rol usuario todos los usuarios del sistema que contengan ese rol asignado pero no me deja al solo poder usar un modelo en la vista, por lo tanto estoy buscando alguna idea para lograrlo. Intente meter los dos modelos en un viewmodel pero no me funciono

Hasta el momento tengo este codigo en la vista:

```
@model SistemaEmpleoEFG.Models.Rol_Usuario
<h2>Details</h2>

 <div>
<h4>Rol_Usuario</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descripcion)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Descripcion)
    </dd>

</dl>
</div>
<h4>Lista de usuarios en este rol</h4>
@if (ViewBag.UserCount == 0)
 {
<hr />
<p>No se encontraron usuarios con este rol</p>
 }
 <table class="table">

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Usuario)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Correo
        </td>
    </tr>
}
 </table>
  <p>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.idRol_Usuario }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear otro modelo que contenga los dos modelos que requieres en la vista.

Ejemplo:

modelo

```
public class PrincipalModel
{
       public Rol_Usuario rol_Usuario { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<Usuario> usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

en tu controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id) 
{ 
  if (id == null) 
  { 
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); 
  } 
  Rol_Usuario rol_Usuario =db.Rol_Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.IdRol==id); 
  if (rol_Usuario == null) 
  { 
    return HttpNotFound(); 
  } 
  var model = new PrincipalModel 
  {
     rol_Usuario =rol_Usuario
     usuarios = db.UsuarioWhere(u =>u.idUser == rol_Usuario.idUser).ToList()//where usuarios con relacion al rol
  };
  return View(model); 
}
```

en tu vista

```
@model SistemaEmpleoEFG.Models.PrincipalModel

<div>@Model.rol_Usuario.idRol_Usuario</div>
    
@foreach (var u in Model.usuarios)
{
     <h3>@u.name</h3>
     
}
```

Comment: voy a intentarlo, lo que no me quedo claro es lo del controlador. Tengo que meterlo en un metodo? gracias amigo espero tu respuesta

Comment: este seria el controlador detalles      public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Rol_Usuario rol_Usuario = db.Rol_Usuario.Find(id);
            
            if (rol_Usuario == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(rol_Usuario);
        }

Comment: he actualizado la respuesta